# Get all the order ids that are completed in a day by wc_get_orders in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am not getting the order ids that are completed on  a date when using wc_get_orders, if there are 5 orders completed in the day 2022-04-19, then I need to get all the 5 order ids by using the date 2022-04-19. I have tried the below code but it's not working

```
$args = array(
    'status' => "Completed",
    'return' => 'ids',
    'date_completed' => '2022-04-19',
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

print_r($orders);
```

Comment: Hi Amal, isn't the completed order status [`wc-complete`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/adc5b1ba425d1e4ee01c06da16dc984b1b521f4b/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php#L98)? I'd also be curious if you need _both_ the completed status and the date completed params at the same time. But first I would try fixing the status param.

Comment: I agree with @helgatheviking. 

have you tried to get the orders with only the date_complete parameter (just to test)?

See: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#date

Comment: You can try the date_query args in the wc_get_orders()  `                    'date_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'before' => $end_date,
                            'after' => $start_date,
                            'inclusive' => true,
                        ),`

Comment: I have given wc-complete but it's not get worked

Answer (score 2):

You can use WC_Order_Query instead of using wc_get_orders

```
<?php
$args = array(
 'limit' => 9999,
 'return' => 'ids',
 'date_completed' => '2022-04-19',
 'status' => 'wc-completed'
);
$query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
$orders = $query->get_orders();
```

And according to WooCommerce Code Reference (https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-order-functions.html#source-view.93) order status should be 'wc-completed'

Comment: Hi ,  it's not working for a particular date like 2022-04-19

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot with this and I can't get a correct answer with wc_get_orders or WC_Order_Query. I think it may be an issue with the date comparison. I have sorted the issue by taking the order id by SQL query

```
global $wpdb;
$resultnew = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_completed_date' AND CAST(`meta_value` AS date)='{$date}'and post_id in (SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status='wc-completed');");
```

$date will be like 2022-04-19